# Start Emacs with R session and side by side windows?

Tags: emacs, ess

I am very bad at customizing emacs. I desire that if i start with a file ending in ".r", emacs starts maximized, with two windows side by side (vertical division of the frame), in one my source code file, and in the other the ESS R interpreter. If I can understand the example, maybe I can generalize it to other extensions and modes. I still do not get the syntax of hooks in elisp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to use Emacs is to have it always running instead of
opening and closing it all the time.

I suggest that you define a function that would make an existing Emacs
look the way you want:

```
(defun my-R-window-configuration ()
  "Prepare the current emacs frame for R work."
  (interactive)
  ;; maximimize the current frame:
  (set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen 'maximized)
  ;; keep just the current window, presumably containing the R code
  (delete-other-windows)
  ;; create ESS R interaction buffer and go there
  (ess-switch-to-end-of-ESS)
  ;; go back to the code
  (other-window 1))
```

Now you can do <kbd>M-x my-R-window-configuration RET</kbd> in an `R` buffer to get what you want.

Comment: Hey, thanks, this is pretty good. As for me is still more confortable to call emacs separatelly for each file, I still will look for the answer on how to call a function on startup if the name of the opened file ends with certain termination. But this solves 87.6% of my inquiry.